# Do both Godparents/Sponsors have to fulfill all the requirements?

Tags: catholicism, baptism, canon-law, godparents

What if one of the godparents is confirmed and the other is not, but both are Catholic? For instance, what if one potential godparent is confirmed, has taken all of the sacraments so far required, and so on, but the other has only been baptized and is mildly handicapped? According to Catholic Canon Law, can they still both serve as godparents?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  Please consider [registering an account](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to fully take advantage of what this site has to offer.  Also, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn what we are about...  As worded, your question was a pastoral advice problem.  That is, one asking for personal advice.  I have reworded it to avoid this problem without changing the intent of the question.  Feel free re-edit if needed.

Comment: Jolene: does [my answer here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/35803/12563) answer your question? If not,  what can I clarify for you?